# ctx.strokeStyle works, but not ctx.fillStyle without error message

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is my code for making the Vietnamese flag. For some reason, only `strokeStyle` works and not `fillStyle`. I have no clue why. I've tried to remove the red color to only show the yellow color on the canvas but that only makes the whole canvas yellow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no-NB">
<head>
    <title>Canvas Vietnam Flagg</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="ie=edge" />
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            min-height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #canvas {
            background: #f0f0f0;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Vietnam flagg</h1>

<canvas id="canvas" width="640"
        height="426"></canvas>

<script>
    const canvas =document.getElementById('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    // bakgrunn
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(218, 37, 29)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,640, 426);
    // stjerne
    ctx.beginPath();
    // 2-3
    ctx.moveTo(320, 86);
    ctx.lineTo(278, 170);
    // 3-4
    ctx.moveTo(278, 170);
    ctx.lineTo(194, 170);
    // 4-5
    ctx.moveTo(194, 170);
    ctx.lineTo(257, 233);
    // 5-6
    ctx.moveTo(257, 233);
    ctx.lineTo(236, 317);
    // 6-7
    ctx.moveTo(236, 317);
    ctx.lineTo(320, 275);
    // 7-8
    ctx.moveTo(320, 275);
    ctx.lineTo(404, 317);
    // 8-9
    ctx.moveTo(404, 317);
    ctx.lineTo(383, 233);
    // 9-10
    ctx.moveTo(383, 233);
    ctx.lineTo(446, 170);
    // 10-11
    ctx.moveTo(446, 170);
    ctx.lineTo(362, 170);
    // 11-2
    ctx.moveTo(362, 170);
    ctx.lineTo(320, 86);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.beginPath, ctx.closePath);
    ctx.fillStyle ="rgb(255, 255, 0)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.beginPath, ctx.closePath);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to change the order of `strokeStyle` and `fillStyle` but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing useless move operations, you have to continue the drawing from the initial point until you reach it again before filling using the `ctx.fill` method instead of the `ctx.fillRect` like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="no-NB">
<head>
    <title>Canvas Vietnam Flagg</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
          content="ie=edge" />
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            background-color: #333;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            min-height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #canvas {
            background: #f0f0f0;
            border-radius: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Vietnam flagg</h1>

<canvas id="canvas" width="640"
        height="426"></canvas>

<script>
    const canvas =document.getElementById('canvas')
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    // bakgrunn
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(218, 37, 29)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,640, 426);
    // stjerne
    ctx.beginPath();
    // 2-3
    ctx.moveTo(320, 86);
    ctx.lineTo(278, 170);
    // 3-4
    ctx.lineTo(194, 170);
    // 4-5
    ctx.lineTo(257, 233);
    // 5-6
    ctx.lineTo(236, 317);
    // 6-7
    ctx.lineTo(320, 275);
    // 7-8
    ctx.lineTo(404, 317);
    // 8-9
    ctx.lineTo(383, 233);
    // 9-10
    ctx.lineTo(446, 170);
    // 10-11
    ctx.lineTo(362, 170);
    // 11-2
    ctx.lineTo(320, 86);

    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 0)";
    ctx.fillStyle ="rgb(255, 255, 0)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Best luck!